# Zend Paginator - Page Links

Tags: php, zend-framework, jquery, zend-paginator

I have a working paginator. I combine Zend Paginator and jQuery to switch between pages. My problem is that the page links only have a range from 1 to 10 but it should be e.g. from 1 to 13. I can get to page 13 by clicking the forward button but the page link 13 is not displayed.
[image]

Paginator setup:

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator ( 
    new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect ( $programmeList ) );
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage ( 12 )
    ->setCurrentPageNumber ( $this->_getParam ( 'page', 1 ));
```

Pass paginator to the view:

```
if (! $this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest ()) {
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
} else {
    $this->view->currentPage = $paginator->getCurrentPageNumber ();
}
```

And this is how I print page links:

```
foreach ( $this->pagesInRange as $page ) {
    echo '<a href="#" id="page" page="'.$page.'">' . $page . '</a>';
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend_Paginator has a setPageRange method which allows you to specify how many pages to show. It has a default of 10, which explains why $this->pagesInRange is always showing only 10 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Great to hear it worked bob. Here's the link to the manual entry for it: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.configuration.html